# xgboost wrong on single sample

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

I decided to start using xgboost and tested it with single train sample.

```
import xgboost as xgb    

data=[[42]]
dtrain=xgb.DMatrix(data, label=[1])
xgb.train(dict(), dtrain).predict(dtrain)
#array([ 0.90156281], dtype=float32)
dtrain=xgb.DMatrix(data, label=[2])
xgb.train(dict(), dtrain).predict(strain)
#array([ 1.70468843], dtype=float32)
dtrain=xgb.DMatrix(data, label=[3])
xgb.train(dict(), dtrain).predict(strain)
#array([ 2.50781417], dtype=float32)
```

What should I change to get for !single! train data sample ideal prediction for the same test data?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems like default number of iterations used by xgboost is too little. Just passing as argument num_round=100 fixes it